# How to get all tuples related to one passed by parameter in SQL?

Tags: sql

[image]

Using this hipotetical scenario (image above), what is the best way to show the name of the Children related to the Parents' ID passed by parameter?

For example: if I receive 1 as Parents' parameter, I need to show the name for their children. In this case? *Emily, Alexander and Sophia*
if I receive 7 as Parents' parameter, I need to show the Children's name: *Olivia and James*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic SQL:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON b.id = a.children
WHERE  a.parents = 1;
```

You have rather unwieldy column names.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic task that you can solve with a join. As you only want data from table B, while table A must just be looked up for the condition, though, I'd select `FROM b` and have the condition on table A in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select name
from b
where id in (select children from a where parents = 1);
```